# Add entire group to active directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to create a script that queries active directory for a group named $server-Administrators, checks to make sure if the group is in local admins, and if not in local admins adds the group to local admins. I know that get-ADGroup allows you to easily check for if there is an administrator group, however I'm not sure how to add an entire group to AD. I'm aware of add-ADGroupMember, however I don't think that is the cmdlet that would let me add an entire group to active directory.

```
$serverName = hostname
$query = get-adgroup administrators
if ($query == false){
     #add group to local admins
}
```

Does anyone know of a way to add an entire group?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to query AD for the members of Server-Administrators, and then make sure that each member of that group is also in the local Administrators group, correct?

Comment: Managing local groups uses WMI interface or another set of cmdlets, so you probably have to make your cmdlet to add an AD group to local group.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: I want to query AD for the Server-Administrators group to check that it exists in local administrators and if it doesn't exist in local administrators then I want to add the entire group to local administrators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it doesn't look like you're trying to work through a problem (you don't really show any attempts to solve the issue yourself, and only have pseudo-code shown), I'll just give reference to what will solve the question without doing much real work myself.

I flexed my Google muscles and searched for 'powershell local administrators group' and the 6th result showed me the answer to your question (second thing I clicked on, because I can't help but read the Hey Scripting Guy! site first).

Use [Jaap Brasser's script from the TechNet Script Gallery](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Add-AD-UserGroup-to-Local-fe5e9239). The work has already been done, there's no need for you to re-invent the wheel here. Save that script, then run it as described in the in-script help.

```
.\Get-Set-ADAccountasLocalAdministrator.ps1 -Computer 'Server01,Server02' -Trustee YourDomain\Server-Administrators
```